# PostgresQL: Find array length of output from ARRAY_AGG()

Tags: postgresql

How do I count the number of distinct elements in an array object, created by `ARRAY_AGG()` in PostgresQL? Here's a toy example for discussion purposes:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG (first_name || ' ' || last_name) actors
FROM film
```

I have tried `ARRAY_LENGTH()`, `LENGTH()`, etc., like so:

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(a.actors)
FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG (first_name || ' ' || last_name) actors
      FROM film) a;
```

But I get an error:

```
function array_length(integer[]) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 208
```

So I tried (2):

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH( CAST(COALESCE(a.actors, '0') AS integer) )
FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG (first_name || ' ' || last_name) actors
      FROM film) a;
```

but I get the error:

```
malformed array literal: "0"
  Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
  Position: 119
```

Comment: You could just use a `COUNT` at the same level as the `ARRAY_AGG`. Something like: `SELECT ARRAY_AGG (first_name || ' ' || last_name) actors, COUNT(*)
FROM film`

Comment: @jmelesky that doesn't work for my actual use case. There are too many other columns that must be grouped by if I use `COUNT(*)` so the result is just `1` even if there is more than 1 element in the array.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name)` is a bit easier to use and will properly deal with null values and empty strings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the function array_length(anyarray, int) require two elements, array and dimension for example:

```
Select array_length(array[1,2,3], 1);
```

Result:
     3

Answer (score 5):

If you are only dealing with a single dimension array, [`cardinality()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) is easier to use:

```
SELECT cardinality(ARRAY_LENGTH(a.actors))
FROM ( 
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG (first_name || ' ' || last_name) actors
  FROM film
) a;
```

Comment: This looks great. Did you mean `SELECT cardinality(a.actors)` instead of `SELECT cardinality(ARRAY_LENGTH(a.actors))`? (The former worked for me and not the latter.)